# Microsoft Access Providers - userID unique after deleting user or reuse?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm building a website in ASP (C#).
I'm using the Microsoft Access  Membership Provider.
I was wondering if the userID will stay unique after removing the user or if it will be used again when creating a new user.

Answer (score 2):

Every user gets an new, unique ID.
A removed ID won't be used again.

Example:

Last created user has ID 22
New user gets ID 23
User 23 gets removed
A new user gets ID 24 (however 23 is not in use any more)